# Sorting column with select elements changes the table DOM from select to static text for DataTables

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.9.3 for my table.

I am using multi-filtering with a custom filtering plugin for some columns with select elements.

I'm also having a custom (but close to what you can find on datatables.net). plugin for sorting my select columns.

My problem is that when I first sort my column and then filter it, it doesn't work. Analyzing aData in the filter function before sorting, I can see that the it contains the entire select (actually form) element. After I have performed the first sorting the aData contains the selected text only, not the entire form/select. Hence, my custom filtering function doesn't work the second time.

How can I make sure that the aData still contains the entire select/form so my custom plugins works after the first sorting?

My filtering plug-in:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
     function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

     console.log(aData[1]);
     var ret = true;    

     //Loop through all input fields i tfoot that has class 'sl_filter' attached                                              
     $('tfoot .sl_filter').each(function(i, obj){                       

         //$(this) can be used. Get the index of this colum.
         var i2 = $("tfoot input").index($(this));                           
         i2 = oTable.fnVisibleToColumnIndex(i2);

         //Create regexp to math
         var r = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");                                                

         //HTML does not get updated when changing value in select, hence searching for :selected return old value
         //DataTables stores the DOM object oSettings. Hence, get the object and extract the text for the selected value.
         var tr = oSettings.aoData[ iDataIndex ].nTr;                       
         var id = $(aData[i2]).attr('id');

         //Get the text
         var str = "";
         var value = "";
         if($(aData[i2]).is("form")){                           
             value = $("#" + id + " select", tr).val();
             str = $("#" + id + " select option[value='" + value + "']", tr).text();
         }else{                           
             value = $("#" + id, tr).val();
             str = $("#" + id + " option[value='" + value + "']", tr).text();
         }

         /*Test to see if there is a match or if the input value is the default 
            (the initial value of input before it has any fokus/text) */                           
         if(r.test(str) || $(this).val()=="Search"){
                 //Return true only exits this function
                 return true;
         }else{

                 /*Return false returns both function an .each. Retain 'false' in a variable scoped
                             to be reached outside the .each */                                
                 ret = false;
                 return false;
          }
      });
      //Return true or false
      return ret;                        

   }
 );
```

My sort plugin:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-select'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn, iColumnVis){

    iColumn = oSettings.oApi._fnColumnIndexToVisible( oSettings, iColumn );
    var aData = [];
    $( 'td:eq('+iColumn+') select', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings) ).each( function () {    
           aData.push( $.trim($(":selected", this).text()));   
    } );

    return aData;
};
```

It seems like the sort plugin is not only sorting the table but also updating the actual dom for the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must access the data for the table like this:

```
str = $('td:eq(' + i2 + ') option:selected', oSettings.aoData[ iDataIndex ].nTr).text();
```

The reason is that aData can be outdated compared to the dom (aoData).

When doing that I could also make my custom filtering function a bit more light:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
     function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

           var ret = true;                     

           //Loop through all input fields i tfoot that has class 'sl_filter' attached                                              
           $('tfoot .sl_filter').each(function(i, obj){                       

           //$(this) can be used. Get the index of this colum.
           var i2 = $("tfoot input").index($(this));                           

           //Create regexp to math
           var r = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");                                                

           //Get the text                       
           var str = $('td:eq(' + i2 + ') option:selected', oSettings.aoData[ iDataIndex ].nTr).text();

           /*Test to see if there is a match or if the input value is the default 
             (the initial value of input before it has any fokus/text) */                           
           if(r.test(str) || $(this).val()=="Search"){
                 //Return true only exits this function
                 return true;
           }else{

                 /*Return false returns both function an .each. Retain 'false' in a variable scoped
                 to be reached outside the .each */                                
                 ret = false;
                 return false;
           }
         });
         //Return true or false
         return ret;                        
       }
    );
```